# Can't activate 1280 * 720 scaling on my 2K external monitor but 1280 * 800 works

Tags: display, resolution

I'm using a Lenovo 1440p display on my MBP through a DP to TB3 cable. The UI looks way too small on the native resolution so I'd like to achieve a 2x scaling to 1280 * 720. However, it seems I just can't enable 1280 * 720 for some reason, but 1280 * 800 works (although with the black bars on the side because it's 16:10 on a 16:9 monitor.)[image]

In SwitchResX, I can see the 1280*720 HiDPi option but notice that the "scaled" checkbox is unchecked while it should be checked, and selecting it doesn't do anything.

Can anyone spot the problem here?

Comment: What about the one just below?

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't *support* that particular resolution?